# What version of the bible uses color coding to indicate the certainty of words attributed of Jesus?

Tags: hermeneutical-approaches, bible-versions

I attended a religous college for my BS. At some point during my four years there, someone showed me a book/bible which had phrases in the new testament marked using a color code.

The color the phrase was written in indicated the probability that Jesus had actually said that particular thing. I recall the colors being red for phrases that were certain, blue very likely, and gray as only somewhat probable.

I do not know the name of the book, but remember that it was supposedly authored and accepted by the catholic church.

I have been looking for this book for a long time and thought I'd ask here.

**What is the name of this book ?** Any hints or suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I expect this is *[The Five Gospels: What Did Jesus Really Say? The Search for the Authentic Words of Jesus](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/006063040X)*, a product of the "[Jesus Seminar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jesus_Seminar#Methodology)". You can see more about this "version" on Michael Marlowe's "[Bible Research](http://www.bible-researcher.com/5gospels.html)" website.

This is what the Lord's Prayer (from [Matthew 6:7-15](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew+6%3A7-15&version=ESV)) looks like (also the example chosen by Marlowe in his discussion):

[image: Five Gospels sample]

One other comment: OP has a memory that this "bible" was "supposedly authored and accepted by the catholic church". As a [commenter notes](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/28750/what-version-of-the-bible-is-this/28751#comment54006_28750), that isn't the case. The impression may have come from the presence of a number of prominent scholars of Catholic backgrounds involved in the Jesus Seminar. John Meier reflects on the relationship to various religious bodies in his article, "[The Present State of the 'Third Quest' for the Historical Jesus: Loss and Gain](http://www.jstor.org/stable/42614221)", *Biblica* 80.4 (1999): 459-87, and draws attention to:

> writers of such diverse views as John Dominic Crossan, Elisabeth Schüssler Fiorenza, and myself [who] come from Roman Catholic backgrounds. (p. 462)

For one assessment of *The Five Gospels* from a major New Testament scholar, see N.T. Wright's review article, "[Five Gospels but No Gospel: Jesus and the Seminar](http://www.apologeticsinthechurch.com/uploads/7/4/5/6/7456646/nt_wright_on_the_jesus_seminar._pdf.pdf)",  in *Authenticating the Activities of Jesus*, ed. Bruce Chilton and Craig A. Evans (Leiden: Brill, 1999), pp. 83–120.